# Polynomial Regression with N features and degree M on C++

Tags: c++, machine-learning, regression, polynomials

I'm new in ML and I was trying this problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/predicting-office-space-price. One of the observation that they made is that

> "The prices per square foot, are (approximately) a polynomial function
>   of the features in the observation table. This polynomial always has
>   an order less than 4"

So I guess the solution would be a applying a polynomial regression, and I have found a lot of (confusing info) about this but with only 2 features. But in this case they can be at most 5 features, so the answer can be a polynomial like: a*x^5+b*x^2*y^3+c*z^2*x...

So is seems more difficult to find a way for creating or evaluating this polynomial, in a function like:

```
float eval(vector<float> x, vector<float> o)
```

And with this I was hoping to use the same gradient decent that I use on linear regression to minimize the cost function.

Am I doing this right? I right to use polynomial regression? How should I go create and eval that polynomial?

Comment: The problem says the polynomial degree is at most 4, so it shouldn't have `x^5` or `x^2 y^3` terms. There are 5 features, it just means you have up to 5 independent variables and that has nothing to do with the polynomial degree. If the features are `v`, `w`, `x`, `y`, and `z`, then the polynomial in its most generic form is: `a1 v^4 + ... + a5 z^4 + b1 v^3 w + ... + b4 v^3 z + ... + c`. Also, you can still use a linear regression, but you need to change the independent variables from the actual features to the combination of features, like `v^4`, `x^3 z`, `v w^2 y`, ...

Comment: Ok, but whats the way to do that? I need to create all the possibilities before? like 'sum = sum + a4*z^5; sum = + a5 + v*w^2;...' and so on?

Comment: The easiest I can think of is this: each term is a constant times a selection of four values from `X=[1, v, w, x, y, z]` which is 625 terms in total. Now if you have four nested loops from 0 to 5 and a counter that goes from 0 to 625, and then multiply `a[counter]*X[i]*X[j]*X[k]*X[l]*X[m]` where `i`, `j`, `k`, `l`, and `m` are the indices for the loops and `a[counter]` is the coefficient corresponding to each term, that will give you all the terms.

Comment: You might want to ignore some of the terms though, for example only consider multiples of up to two of the features, and not more unless you believe the combined impact of some of the features might be important. This will will reduce the number of terms by a lot.

Comment: The problem I find with that four nested loops solution is that I would repeat values, for example: with i=1, j=1, k=1, l=2 and m=1 the sum will be `1*1*1*V*1` and with i=2, j=1, k=1, l=1 and m=1 will be `v*1*1*1*1`. So I was thinking that a better option is a nested loop that look like this:
 
`for(int i=0;i<x.size();i++)
    for(int j=i;j<x.size();j++)
       for(int k=j;m<x.size();m++)
          for(int l=k;l<x.size();l++)
             for(int m=l;m<x.size();m++){`

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Sorry for the confusion. Also, you just need `i`, `j`, `k`, and `l`, no need for the last loop as you want the degree to be four and not five.